# How to iterate through a list in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

```
sampleDict={ “A1”:[“234-234-2234”, [“Brown”, “Bill”] ], “B2”:[“654-564-5564”,[“Jones”,”Jennifer”]] }
```

I have to check to see it `"john"` is in the dictionary and print the first and last name of everyone whose phone number begins with `"654"`

and my code is:

```
for i in sampleDict.keys():    
    for key in sampleDict[i]:
        print(key)
```

and how do i just print the last name in the list : "Brown"

Comment: So what is the problem with your code?

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket for the `sampleDict['B2']` list.

Comment: code works fine but i am not able to iterate through the keys in the dictionary for example if i want to only print out the last name of the person

Comment: I think you might not be using the term `key` in the same meaning as it's used for Python dictionaries.  In your `sampleDict`, the keys are `"A1"`, `"B2"`, while the values are `[“234-234-2234”, [“Brown”, “Bill”] ]` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can access the different parts of the dictionary values through list indexing:

```
for (k,v) in sampleDict.iteritems():
    key          = k
    phone_number = v[0]
    last_name    = v[1][0]
    first_name   = v[1][0]
    # Do something
```

Each value is just a 2-element list, the first element corresponding to the phone number, and the second element, itself a list, with elements corresponding to the last and first name.

But you could write the functions you're looking for with something like:

```
def is_john_here(d):
    for v in d.values():
        if v[1][1] == "john": return True
    return False

print is_john_here(sampleDict)  # False
```

Or

```
def find_people_by_number(d, prefix):
    for v in d.values():
        if v[0].startswith(prefix):
            print ', '.join(v[1])

find_people_by_number(sampleDict, '654')  # Jones, Jennifer
```

Or (from comments)

```
def last_names(d):
    for v in d.values():
        print v[1][0]

last_names(sampleDict)    # Brown
                          # Jones
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't care about the `key`?

```
for values in sampleDict.values():
    lname = values[1][0] # Assuming that last name is always the first element
    fname = values[1][1] # Assuming that first name is always the second element
    # Checking if `name` is in names list
    if 'john' in values[1]:
        # do whatever
```

Comment: Thank you @slik and can i get the code to only print the last name of the keys in the dictionary

Comment: Np. As Jedwards mentioned you can access parts of the dictionary. I'll update my answer as well